# How to implement thread to add a timer to my game?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've written the MVP for a game. But now I would like to add a stopwatch to it, so that the player can see time being counted down in the bottom left or right corner of the game. This isn't a question about how to create such a stop watch, its about how to include it in my game.

I've figured out how to render the clock digits onto the screen, but the problem is that when I use any input to trigger off the clock the game remains stuck in the clock loop. Here is some code to explain:

```
// when the player makes her first input the clock is triggered

if (!CLOCK)
    this->clockStatus(ON);


// within the clockStatus function
void Game::clockStatus(TimerState Status)
{
    do {                             /* Infinite Loop */
        t2->getTimefromSeconds(getCurrentSysTime());
        break;
    } while (1);
    while (1) {                        /* Another infinite loop */
        t_inter->getTimefromSeconds(getCurrentSysTime());
        t1 = (Timer*)(t_inter - t2);
    }
}
```

The output of t1 is displayed via:

```
t1.display();
```

For clarity, TimeState is an enum that manages the stopwatch state.(ON/OFF) Timer is the actual stopwatch class.

After researching I have concluded that when the player makes their first input into the game, which triggers off the stopwatch, I should create a new thread for this. This way the main function can run normal and the secondary thread can calculate game time. Is there any tutorial or pdf or exercise that I can read on how to implement this? Also all helpful suggestions will be welcome.

Comment: Surmising that you need `threads` in this situation, you're halfway there. It would be helpful to know what kind of platform you are using for your display/rendering. For example if you are using Qt, you can easily use Qt's Timer class. It's widget display system is multi-threaded as is.

Comment: What is `Timer`, and what type are `t1`, `t2`, and `t_inter`?

Comment: Im using OpenGL and GLFW. But I wish to write the stopwatch using C++

Comment: To *measure* the time, you can use [C++'s standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono). To *display* it, just evaluate the difference at each frame. No need for an infinite loop. No threads either.

Comment: The stopwatch has to show the time being incremented. Perhaps you could write some example code?

Comment: For thread implementation, you can refer to this site: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to be able to start a stopwatch and then display the time elapsed since it was started. The easiest way to do that is to store the start time, and then (in your normal render loop) find the difference from the current time. You could use this helper class:

```
#include <chrono>

inline auto currentTime() {
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

struct Timer {
    Timer() { reset(); }
    void reset() { // reset the stopwatch to 0
        startTime = currentTime();
    }
    double getElapsed() { // get the elapsed time (in seconds)
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
                  currentTime() - startTime
               ).count() / 1000000000.0;
    }
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> startTime;
};
```

Example usage:

```
// global
Timer stopwatch;

// when the player does first input (or whenever)
stopwatch.reset();

// in your loop
double stopwatchSeconds = stopwatch.getElapsed();
// display the value...
```

Comment: thank you qxz, after a few modifications your example works well!

Comment: @MagnusHimmler Don't forget to accept qxz's answer if it solves your problem.